# Laravel 5 Route Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view, routes

I`m new to laravel 5.4 so that i need to call these 2 functions in one view.
here is the 2 controllers.

```
 public function index()
{
   $items = trainingprogramedetails::all()->last();
     return view('programesession/index',compact('items'));

}

 public function list()
{
   $lists = trainingprogramedetails::all();
     return view('programesession/index',compact('lists'));

}
```

Here is my view index.blade.php

```
<thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Data</th>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>{{ $items->date_of_programe }}</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>Time</td>
                <td>{{ $items->time }}</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>{{ $items->venue }}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
```

```
             <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>

                <th>Trainee Programe ID</th>
                <th>Presenter Name</th>
                <th>Division</th>
                <th>Date</th>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
              @foreach($lists as $item)

                 <tr>

              <td>{{ $item->training_programe_id }}</td>
              <td>{{ $item->presenter_name }}</td>
              <td>{{ $item->division }}</td>
              <td>{{ $item->date }}</td>
          </tr>
                @endforeach

              </tbody>
      </table>
```

So that this the error getting here.
[image]

Here is my Rout

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
Route::resource('/programelist', 'TrainingProgrameSeassion');
```

});

Can you please help met to solve this?

Comment: And why do you think it is an issue with the routes? Did you even read the error message?

Comment: i`m new to the laravel.whatever the case this is for my undergraduate project i have to do it using laravel.i thought it is route issue.if i know it i dont ask it as a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the question, i came to know that you are you might be calling the `index()` function and not the `list()` function when calling the index route.

The question is not much clear and needs further clarification.

You need to use both variable in single function to achieve the solution.

```
public function index()
{
    $items = trainingprogramedetails::all()->last();
    $lists = trainingprogramedetails::all();

    return view('programesession/index', compact('items', 'lists'));
}
```

The error is caused because you either call the index method or the list method and not both and pass only `items` variables in the view and the `lists` variable in not there.

If the answer is not what you want then please add further codes and elaborate your question.

Comment: Glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need update your view like:

```
@if(isset($items))
<table>
<thead>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Data</th>
         </thead>

         <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td>Date</td>
               <td>{{ $items->date_of_programe }}</td>
             </tr>

             <tr>
               <td>Time</td>
               <td>{{ $items->time }}</td>
             </tr>

             <tr>
               <td>Venue</td>
               <td>{{ $items->venue }}</td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
@endif

@if(isset($lists))
            <table class="table table-striped">
             <thead>

               <th>Trainee Programe ID</th>
               <th>Presenter Name</th>
               <th>Division</th>
               <th>Date</th>
             </thead>

             <tbody>
             @foreach($lists as $item)

                <tr>

             <td>{{ $item->training_programe_id }}</td>
             <td>{{ $item->presenter_name }}</td>
             <td>{{ $item->division }}</td>
             <td>{{ $item->date }}</td>
         </tr>
               @endforeach

             </tbody>
     </table>
@endif
```

Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to combine the two functions? The other solution should handle the current error. If you do need two functions, it may be best to use partials as well

```
public function index()
{
   $items = trainingprogramedetails::all()->last();
   $lists = trainingprogramedetails::all();
   return view('programesession/index',compact('lists','items'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use Like this proper code

```
    public function index()
{
   $items = trainingprogramedetails::all()->last();

return view('programesession.index')->with(compact('items'));

}

 public function list()
{
   $lists = trainingprogramedetails::all();

return view('programesession.index')->with(compact('lists'));

}
```